# infinite loading when trying to post data to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating rest api , i have end point for post /review  which are returned from external api themoviedb, I want those review to be saved in my mongodb.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
app.post('/data', (req, res) => {
        // Create the HTTP POST.
        request('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/401478/reviews?api_key=4d9c9de3bdf0d3b6837c49c086e3b190', function (error, response, body) {
        var str = '';
        // Create the listener for data being returned.
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                str += chunk;
            });
                // Create the listener for the end of the POST.
            response.on('end', function (){
                    db.collection('data').insert(str, (err, result) => {
                        if (err) {
                            res.send({
                                'error': 'An error has occured'
                            });
                        } else {
                            res.send(result.ops[0]);
                        }
                    });
            });
        });
    });
```

when I run localhost:8000/review on postman post, It keeep loading  no result are displayed, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what happens when you console log result ?

Comment: @feiiiiii hii, I am new to this, i am using post man to test my api but I am not able to check console log as in chrome, tried but its still just loading, but is this the right way of doing it? if I want to save data from external api?

Comment: you are using terminal/command line though right ? so what do you see when you run your node app if you add console log result ?

Comment: @feiiiiii app running on port 8000 nothing more, after waiting and waiting in postman it return error "could not get  any rensponse"

Comment: so you added console.log(result) under db.collection.insert and still nothing when you post to localhost:8000/data ? can you console.log(req)  right after app.post , does it show anything there ?

Comment: 'body: {},
  _body: true,
  length: undefined,
  read: [Function],
  route: Route { path: '/review', stack: [ [Object] ], methods: { post: true } } }' @feiiiiii after i run post send this is what I get in console

Comment: if you console.log(body) inside request you should see the str you want to save inside your mongodb right ?. it seems to me the problem is that response.on was not triggered there for its not doing anything after it makes request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.post('/data', (req, res) => {
    let url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/401478/reviews?api_key=4d9c9de3bdf0d3b6837c49c086e3b190';
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        db.collection('data').insert(body, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send({
                    'error': 'An error has occured'
                });
            } else {
                    res.send(result.ops[0]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also, why you are making a post req? and as per your code, the API req should be localhost:8000/data not localhost:8000/review.

Comment: i get error TypeError: Cannot create property '_id' on string  ... with review data infront of it